# how can I add an Image to my javascript If statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.invoices.length; i++) {

  var unix_timestamp = data.invoices[i].invoiceDate;

var date = new Date(unix_timestamp);
// hours part from the timestamp
var day = date.getDate();
// minutes part from the timestamp
var mnth = (date.getMonth())+1;
// seconds part from the timestamp
var yr = date.getFullYear();

var p = "";

if(data.invoices[i].paid == false) {
p = "Outstanding";
} else {
  p = "Paid";
}


if(i%2 == 1) {
  tableRow = '<tr>';
} else {
tableRow = '<tr class="EDBGreyBackground">';
}

tableRow += '<td height="40" valign="middle" align="left">'+day+'-'+mnth+'-'+yr+'</td>';
tableRow += '<td height="40" valign="middle" align="left">&pound;'+data.invoices[i].amountDue+'</td>';
tableRow += '<td height="40" valign="middle" align="left">'+p+'</td>';
tableRow += '<td height="40" valign="middle" align="left"><a href="'+data.invoices[i].printableBill+'"><img class="floatNone" width="25" height="25" border="0" alt="PDF" src="images/EDB_PDF_icon.png"></a></td>';
tableRow += '</tr>';

$('#previousBillhistory').append(tableRow);

  }
```

I am trying to change the word PAID in my IF statement to an image, can anyone point me in the right direction please.

thank you

Updated with the whole code snippet.

Thank you again

Comment: Do you have more details of the script? `p` is a javascript variable, you won't be able to set it to an image, it's code. You could set `p` to the address of an image. Is there an element on a page that you want to set to an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `div` and change its content given paid value:

```
<div id="yourImageDiv"></div>
```

And then in your code try something like:

```
if(data.invoices[i].paid == false){
    p = "Outstanding";
} else {
    $('#yourImageDiv').empty();
    $('#yourImageDiv').html('<img id="img" src="img.png" />')
}
```

**After the update of your question**.... it is more simple what you need. Simply do this:

```
if(data.invoices[i].paid == false) {
    p = "<img src='Outstanding_image.png' />"; 
} else {
    p = "<img src='Paid_image.png' />";
}
```

Comment: Thank you I will try that, its much appreciated, im kinda new to this.

Comment: @JayBarker You are welcome! After your question update I've modified my answer.

Comment: Both worked liked a charm, but i chose the simple approach as im a beginner. thank you all for your help. Its much appreciated.

Comment: @JayBarker When you think that an answer or a question is useful you click the up triangle near the the top of the question or the answer. When an answer resolve your problem you click the gray v to mark it as accepted